# npm install ember@2.18 gives SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js

When I try to run `$ npm install` to install all modules on project, or when trying to install ember v 2.18 with `$ npm install ember@2.18` it gives me the error:

```
npm http GET https://www.npmjs.com/ember
npm http 200 https://www.npmjs.com/ember
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <!doctype html>
npm ERR! <html>
. . .
. . .
npm ERR! </html>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/home/felipe/.nvm/v0.8.16/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:226:23)
npm ERR!     at Request.init.self.callback (/home/felipe/.nvm/v0.8.16/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:120:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/felipe/.nvm/v0.8.16/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:648:16)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.Request.start.self.req.self.httpModule.request.buffer (/home/felipe/.nvm/v0.8.16/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:610:14)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64
npm ERR! command "/home/felipe/.nvm/v0.8.16/bin/node" "/home/felipe/.nvm/v0.8.16/bin/npm" "install" "ember@2.18"
npm ERR! cwd /workspace/.../projects/...
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.16
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.69
npm ERR! type unexpected_token
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: 'npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64
npm ERR! command "/home/felipe/.nvm/v0.8.16/bin/node" "/home/felipe/.nvm/v0.8.16/bin/npm" "install" "ember@2.18"
npm ERR! cwd /workspace/.../projects/...
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.16
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.69
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /workspace/.../projects/.../npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried with `sudo`, no luck.
I also tried to uninstall NPM and NodeJS, but no luck also.

How do I fix that? Is this a problem with my NPM or NodeJS installation?

Comment: Run `$ npm view ember versions` via your CLI  to show all versions available for _ember_ - you'll see that version `2.18` does not exist.

Comment: Strangely, this command outputs the same error, and doesn't show the ember versions. Now I'm sure it is something with my env. I try removing and installing it all again. Thanks!

Comment: Try running `$ npm cache clear`

Comment: Still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default npm registry can be found at;

- `https://registry.npmjs.org/`

However, (according to your error log), yours appears to be currently set to:

- `https://www.npmjs.com/`

Try running the following [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) command to set the registry:

```
$ npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: I had this config to solve another problem with SSL, but I didn't expect it to create another. This solved the problem! Thank you!